# Cal functions of same name from different files

Tags: php

For my site, i intend on having several add-ons. At the moment i am able to get what plugins are required by the user, but i am unsure of how to include them.

I have structured my directories such that the plugins are all in a directory called `plugins`, and then each plugin is within a directory under that, and then each plugins directory has an `init.php` file that i want to call. With the build array of the scanned dir as such:

`Array ( [2] => forums [3] => mesages [4] => profile [5] => clock)`

And the corresponding directories array becoming:

```
Array (
[2] => plugins/forums/init.php
[3] => plugins/mesages/init.php
[4] => plugins/profile/init.php
[5] => plugins/something/init.php
)
```

My problem/question is how do i call these `init.php`'s functions. I if i were to do a `foreach` through the array and somehow `require()` them, then simply calling a function from `init.php` could be from any of the plugins.

I have considered having the functions named like `clock_init()` but i would like to avoid that if possible. Any suggestions for my predicament?

Comment: Why don't you just execute the init-code, when you include the init-script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way using global functions.

Although if you use classes for your plugin functions then you can do something like this:

```
foreach($plugins as $plugin) { 
  include "$plugin.php";
  $klas = new $plugin();
  $klas::method();
}
```

Your plugin class:

```
class forums {
  function forums() { ... }
  function method() { ... }
}
```

The above code is untested but it is pretty much the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Initiall you could have this array combined into one, using the key as the include type, like so:

```
$inits = array(
  'forums' => 'plugins/forums/init.php',
  'messages' =>  'plugins/messages/init.php'
);
```

You could then iterate / call whichever you require.

```
if (I WANT TO RUN FORUM INIT)
{
   include $inits['forums'];
   initFunction();
}
```

Personally, I'd have each one of these as a class and set up an interface. These will then implement a consistent method name (declared in my interface) such as init().

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php